# npm link-ing package with bin does not work

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm working locally on a multi-module project. I have one module which has a `bin` that it publishes:

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "bin": "bin/index.js",
  "dependencies": { "third-party": "*" }
}
```

I then have another module which wants to use this `bin`:

```
{
  "name": "b",
  "dependencies": { "a": "*" }
}
```

From the directory of `a`, I run `npm link`. Then from the directory of `b`, I run `npm link a`. This gets them linked up, and I get `a` in `b`'s `node_modules/.bin`.

So far, so good.

Now, the problem is `a` has `dependencies` which `b` doesn't have, so when I try to run the binary from `b`'s directory, it tries to run the `bin` with a current working directory of `b`'s directory. So, it looks there for the `node_modules` and doesn't find them, which throws an error.

If `a` was a regular (non-linked) dependency, all of it's `dependencies` would be installed into `b`'s `node_modules`. That doesn't happen with `npm link` though, so it doesn't work.

What is the least hacky method I can use to get this to work? Is there a "proper" approach to this?

---

If it matters, I'm using `lerna`. I'm working with Git Bash on Windows. Latest Node version 9.3.0 and associated `npm`.